# prove or disprove that $[∫f(x)g(x)\,dx]^2 ≤ ∫f(x)^2dx ∫g(x)^2dx$ for all $f$ and $g$ over any interval

Tags: calculus

I have managed to prove that if $f$ and $g$ have this property that $f$ and $f+g$ will also have the property but I have failed to prove that it is true in general. Ideally, the proof would use only first year calculus as that is all I am familiar with.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

For all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, $$P(\lambda)=\int (f(x)+\lambda g(x))^2 \ dx = \int f^2(x) \ dx + 2\lambda \int f(x)g(x) \ dx +\lambda^2 \int g^2(x) \ dx \ge 0$$ Hence the discriminant of this degree two polynomial is non positive. This provides the result.

Comment: Classic Cauchy-Schwarz proof (+1!).  It is notable that one can extend this to the complex case without too much difficulty by expressing $\lambda$ in polar form.